# Как в Golang узнать реальное имя системной папки?

Tags: golang

Как в Golang узнать реальное имя системной папки?
Нужно создать файл в каталоге программных файлов Windows
Например %ProgramFiles% - не работает.
Как узнать папку програмных файлов / операционной системы и др. ?

Comment: Какое-нибудь ExpandEnvironmentStrings вызвать попробуйте...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.getenv` вам поможет - *golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv*